# Global event hook that fires once when either Cypress run or open is called

Tags: cypress

Is there a Cypress event hook that is called one time when either cypress run or cypress open are used?

I know that there is the plugins file on('before:browser:launch') that will run before cypress open (https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Modify-args-based-on-browser) but will this also run before cypress run?

Not sure which event I should hook into to fire off some Node code before either cypress open or run are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `support/index.js` file is usually ideal for this kind of setup code. It does run before every spec file, not just once on startup, but you can usually put anything you need to set up in there.

It's also worth having a read of [the CI docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Boot-your-server) if you haven't already, as they point out potential pitfalls with running processes before Cypress. If your code is a simple "run then exit successfully" scenario, you could always go with:

```
node foo.js && cypress run
```

It's when the node process is backgrounded that things can get a bit hairy.

Comment: I've read through the docs and looked through their kitchen sink code examples and couldnt find this hook. My current solution is to do what you've suggested using npm scripts. The problem with this is that for every npm script I have that calls cypress open or run, I have to remember to put in the code I want to run before Cypress, which isn't a very clean solution. I'm pretty amazed they don't have a global event that fires when Cypress starts (not before each test run). Say I want to download some .spec files from an S3 bucket only once when Cypress starts or get a bearer token?

Comment: Yeah sounds like you're talking npm script territory there. Alternatively, low-rent solutions like bash aliases can be very effective for this sort of thing. Doesn't have to be all-JS! ;)